# Showing Trademark (TM) in select dropdown option under select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following simple select tag with few options, I would like add trademark (TM) in option value in upper position of title but `<sup>` tag is not changing anything.

What are the other way to display TM in upper position of options?

```
<select>
  <option>Option Value TM</option>
  <option>Option Value</option>
  <option>Option Value</option>
  <option>Option Value</option>
  <option>Option Value</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use ascii `™` mark or `&#8482;` as html

```html
<select>
  <option>Option Value ™</option>
  <option>Option Value &#8482;</option>
  <option>Option Value</option>
  <option>Option Value</option>
  <option>Option Value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: For simplicity, I think `&trade;` will also work, I use it a lot in HTML.